# is getClientIp() enough to identify a user

Tags: php, symfony, ip

I'm working on a symfony project and I want to allow users to add products to the cart before they sign up
my idea is to identify the users using the getClientIp()
is this function enough to identify users or do I need to use other functions

Comment: Absolutely not. IPs are subject to change (and potentially one client could even get the IP of another within a couple minutes if their ISP decides so). You should rather use some sort of session management system. I am sure there is one in PHP/symphony (though I don't know enough to recommend one)

Comment: What if two people using the same router? Then they'll have the same IP.

Comment: what if a user with a DSL connection get's a connection lost? he get's a new ip. So the answer has to be "no" again ;)

Comment: Another idea would be to store the cart in the client (in localStorage, for example) until they have registered. The upside with that is that they can keep the same cart if they close the site down and revisit it later from the same browser.

Comment: Normally you use PHP sessions for that. Maybe take a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html or https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.session.php. The session handling will take care of the task you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use an IP address to identify a specific user.

Why?

- One public IP address can be shared by multiple users and devices - examples of this scenario include users behind a NAT router on a domestic network, or users behind a proxy server or gateway on an organisational network.
- Equally one user or device can use multiple IP addresses. One user can use multiple devices, which can be connected to different IP addresses, and can even switch networks or IP address during one session of usage. Examples of this include switching from Wifi to Mobile data connection by a portable device, or a device/router being allocated a new public IP by their ISP via DHCP.

---

To address your specific requirement:

If, in your application, you want to allow users to add items to their cart before signing up, one option is you can store that data in the Session in PHP. Session data persists on the server for the duration of the current browser session (this is managed by cookies and doesn't depend on a user having logged into your application, and doesn't depend on their IP address either).

Then if the user registers an account during the same session, you keep that Session data and it becomes that specific user's cart. (You can then, for example, more easily do things like have a cart which persists between browser sessions and across all devices where the same user is logged in, because you can tie it to the user record in the database.)

Comment: thank you for your answer I'm going to see if sessions would do the job

Comment: I'm quite sure it will.

Answer (score 0):

Authetification and Identification is a complex part of programming.

It's not enough to check an IP-Address (what can simply be changed by several actions).

Because you tagged your Question with Symfony, have a look on the Symfony Security package to get it working for you.

Hope this helps you.